# How to clear firebase Push notification from status bar android programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

I can clear the notification that is pushed from the app with this code

```
val notificationIds: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
notificationIds.forEach {
    notificationManager.cancel(it)
}
```

it works with when I save notification Id at every notify 
but now I didn't have firebase notification id

Answer (score 1):

Better to Delete All Notifications rather to keep notification id

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to send data messages from Firebase and with that you can create notification with id manually. Hence, you would be able to cancel/clear notification.